# How to catch slick postgres exceptions for duplicate key value violations

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

My table has a unique index on a pair of columns in my postgresql database.

I want to know how I can catch a duplicate key exception when I am inserting:

```
def save(user: User)(implicit session: Session): User = {
  val newId = (users returning users.map(_id) += user
  user.copy(id = newId)
}
```

My logs show this exception:

```
Execution exception[[PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "...."
```

I haven't really used exceptions much in scala either yet also.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your `save` method should probably return something different than just `User`, to indicate the possibility of failure. If the only exception that will be thrown is by unique key, and you really only care about success or failure (and not the type of failure), one way to go would be to return `Option[User]`.

You could use a simple `try/catch` block, mapping successful saves to `Some[User]` and  `PSQLException` to `None`:

```
def save(user: User)(implicit session: Session): Option[User] = {
  try {
    val newId = (users returning users.map(_id) += user
    Some(user.copy(id = newId))
  } catch {
      case PSQLException => None
  }
}
```

Personally not the way I'd go, as `try/catch` isn't really idiomatic Scala, and your error type is discarded. The next option is to use `scala.util.Try`.

```
def save(user: User)(implicit session: Session): Try[User] = Try {
  val newId = (users returning users.map(_id) += user
  user.copy(id = newId)
}
```

The code here is simpler. If the body of `Try` is successful, then `save` will return `Success[User]`, and if not it will return the exception wrapped in `Failure`. This will allow you to do many things with `Try`.

You could pattern match:

```
save(user) match {
   case Success(user) => Ok(user)
   case Failure(t: PSQLException) if(e.getSQLState == "23505") => InternalServerError("Some sort of unique key violation..")
   case Failure(t: PSQLException) => InternalServerError("Some sort of psql error..")
   case Failure(_) => InternalServerError("Something else happened.. it was bad..")
}
```

You could use it like `Option`:

```
save(user) map { user =>
   Ok(user)
} getOrElse {
   InternalServerError("Something terrible happened..")
}
```

You can compose many together at once, and stop on the first failure:

```
(for {
   u1 <- save(user1)
   u2 <- save(user2)
   u3 <- save(user3)
} yield {
  (u1, u2, u3)
}) match {
   case Success((u1, u2, u3)) => Ok(...)
   case Failure(...) => ...
}
```

Comment: wow, terrific information thanks.  Just to clarify, to single out a 'duplicate key' would I have to parse the string message returned from the message to figure out if it was a duplicate key erorr? (as oppose to other psqlexecptions).

Comment: Either that or by matching the SQL state. I don't use postgres, so I'm not sure if this is 100% accurate (mysql uses error codes), but for example `case e: PSQLException if(e.getSQLState == "23505") => ...` See this page: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html

Comment: match the output of Try to scalaz disjunctions and you can model the contract of your methods nicely. makes for a great API which is easy to work with

Comment: newbie question: what's the implicit session?

Answer (score 16):

In Slick 3.x you can use `asTry`.

I'm using MySQL, but the same code can be used for PostgreSQL, only the exceptions are different.

```
import scala.util.Try
import scala.util.Success
import scala.util.Failure

db.run(myAction.asTry).map {result =>  

  result match {

    case Success(res) => 
      println("success")
      // ...

    case Failure(e: MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) => {
      //code: 1062, status: 23000, e: Duplicate entry 'foo' for key 'name'
      println(s"MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException, code: ${e.getErrorCode}, sql status: ${e.getSQLState}, message: ${e.getMessage}")
      // ...
    }

    case Failure(e) => {
      println(s"Exception in insertOrUpdateListItem, ${e.getMessage}")
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Note: It's also possible to map the action (`myAction.asTry.map ...`) instead of the future returned by `db.run`.

Comment: what are the classes `DBResult` and `DBStatus`? I don't see them in slick scaladoc

Comment: These are my own classes. "I also use a result wrapper with a custom status code for all my database results.". I'll remove them to avoid confusion.