# Slick: Return inserted row with auto increment id

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, slick

I'm trying to make an insert into a MySQL table and to return the row with the auto increment id. My code is below:

```
private val Log = TableQuery[GCMLogTable]

def save(log: GCMLog): Try[GCMLog] = Try {
    val newId = (Log returning Log.map(_.id)) += log
    log.copy(id = newId)
}
```

But my compilation fails for my code with the below error:

```
type mismatch;
    found   : slick.profile.FixedSqlAction[Long,slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.Write]
    required: Long
```

Also tried

```
def save(log: GCMLog): Try[GCMLog] = Try {
    (Log returning Log.map(_.id)
      into ((log, newId) => log.copy(id = newId))
      ) += log
}
```

But still fails with

```
type mismatch;
found   : slick.profile.FixedSqlAction[models.GCMLog,slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.Write]
required: models.GCMLog
```

[I referred the SO question [How to catch slick postgres exceptions for duplicate key value violations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080868/how-to-catch-slick-postgres-exceptions-for-duplicate-key-value-violations) and Slick documentation here http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/queries.html ]

Much appreciated if someone can tell me what's going on and how this can be fixed.

Thanks!

Comment: I think your problem (type mismatch) is because you're not actually running your query ```db.run(...)```.

Comment: @MirkoStocker db.run works (with a different syntax), but is there a way to return the inserted row if I use db.run?

Comment: So what does your code currently return when you do a db.run?

Comment: @MirkoStocker I just got it to work. I rewrote it and now it's working with db.run. Not even sure what I've been doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: MySQL or Postgres -- Which??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 def save(log: GCMLog): Try[GCMLog] = Try {
    (Log returning Log.map(_.id))
       into ((log, newId) => log.copy(id = newId))
        ) += log
  }
```

UPDATE:

It looks `db.run` needs to be perform to convert that `Action` into result.

Comment: It doesn't work either. I've edited my question with the error.

Comment: @shyam It looks like `db.run` needs to be done to convert `Action` into result

Comment: Trying different things, still can't get it to work. :(

Answer (score 2):

slick supports it:

```
def create(objectToCreate: MyCaseClass): MyCaseClass = {
    db.withSession {
      (self returning self) += objectToCreate
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private val Log = TableQuery[GCMLogTable]
private val db = Database.forConfig("mysql")

def save(log: GCMLog): Try[GCMLog] = Try {
    val newId = db.run((Log returning Log.map(_.id) into ((Log,id) => Log.copy(id=id))) += log)
    Await.result(newId, Duration.Inf)
}
```