# Scala slick how can I return my own Error message

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

I have a registration Action that asks for user emails, in my postgres database I only allow unique emails. When I put in a duplicate email I get back the error message

```
    **Failure(org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates 
unique constraint "same_name_profiles_email"
      Detail: Key (email)=(gtff@gmail.com) already exists.)**
```

I would like to return my own generic error message instead, something similar to what they are doing here [How to catch slick postgres exceptions for duplicate key value violations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080868/how-to-catch-slick-postgres-exceptions-for-duplicate-key-value-violations)  .
The issue I am facing is that I am getting an error of

```
**constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : akka.actor.FSM.Failure
 required: scala.util.Try[Int]**
```

What I would like to do is to show the error message code and sqlState code . This is my code

```
   def registration = Action.async {implicit request=>

      val setup =
        sqlu"""INSERT Logic"""

      db.run(setup.asTry).map { result =>
    if(result.isFailure)
      {

        result match {

          case Failure(e: PSQLException) => {
            //code: if Error I would like to return message below
            Ok(s"PostgresIntegrityConstraintViolationException, code:    ${e.getErrorCode}, sql status: ${e.getSQLState}, message: ${e.getMessage}")

          }
        }


      }
        Ok(result.toString())

        }

    }
```

Whenever there is an error in the Database it falls inside the **result.isFailure** now I would just like to get the PSQLException ErrorCode and SQLState . I do not really care about matching or anything. I am doing this for a web service API so if for example I see that error code 23008 corresponds with duplicate email then I can give user's a generic message such as "Duplicate Email" . Any suggestions would be great as I'm new to Scala and Slick . I am using slick version 3.11

The error message is coming from this part

```
      result match {

          case Failure(e: PSQLException) => {
            //code: if Error I would like to return message below
            Ok(s"PostgresIntegrityConstraintViolationException, code:    ${e.getErrorCode}, sql status: ${e.getSQLState}, message: ${e.getMessage}")

          }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering i understood your question correctly, you can use nested Case.
Inside the case check the error code, if the error code is as expected show the Msg.

```
case Failure(e: PSQLException) => e.code match{
    case "23008" => println("Duplicate email")
        case - => println("Some generic msg")    
            }
```

Please let me know if I understood it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The error messages

```
constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
  found   : akka.actor.FSM.Failure
  required: scala.util.Try[Int]
```

seems to indicate that you are referring to the wrong Failure type. It is not the subtype of Try but the one from akka.

Perhaps check your imports?

Answer (score 0):

- Use .recoverWith {     case _: OwnException()}
- Or .recover also works.

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala